# MessagePack and Subclasses deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, polymorphism, msgpack

I am playing around with MessagePack and Java. I have had experience with Protobuf and Json (using Jackson and Gson) in the past when it comes to serialization tools.

When it comes to normal serialization and deserialization I have no problems at all. It is when I want to have multiple subclasses of another class that a problem arise.

I am testing this with the following code :

TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass sub = new TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass();
        byte[] pack = MsgPack.pack(sub);
        Assert.assertTrue(ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(pack));

```
    List<? extends TestMessage> msg = MsgPack.unpack(pack, TestMessage.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(msg);
    Assert.assertFalse(msg.isEmpty());
    TestMessage temp = msg.get(0);

    Assert.assertNotNull(temp);
    Assert.assertTrue(temp instanceof TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass);
    TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass sub2 = (TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass) temp;
    Assert.assertEquals(sub, sub2);

    System.out.println(sub);
    System.out.println(sub2);
```

Those two lines fail because when I deserialize I only get a normal TestMessage, and not a TestMessageSubClass instance.

```
    Assert.assertTrue(temp instanceof TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass);
    TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass sub2 = (TestMessage.TestMessageSubClass) temp;
```

I suppose that this happens because by default the MessagePack unpacker has no way of determining the exact class of he needs to deserialize. In fact this would work just fine if I directly ask him to deserialize into a TestMessageSubClass.

My requirements is that TestMessage might have any number of subclasses with extra data, and with the same code I need to de-serialize them in the right class instance without losing anything. I might be deserializing a stream containing an heterogeneous list of those TestMessage instances.

I can have the behaviour I want using the @[JsonSubTypes annotation in JacksonJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378776/deserialize-json-to-classes).

Is there a way to use the official MessagePack client API and obtain that? Is there a known pattern to do that myself?

Here is the code of my MsgPack wrapper class: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6112229)

Any advice on using MessagePack more efficiently is welcome too.

Comment: Hey, have you solved your subclass deserialization problem in the meantime?

Comment: Nope, gave up on that solution and used something else.